# code docent work serial monitor and servos

Tags: python, arduino

I'm trying to control 2 servos with my mouse. I have a python program looking for my mouse cords and sending them to the Arduino through the serial monitor. I can run both programs without it stopping me but when I run them to work with each nothing happens the python program was made to print out my cords so I know if it is working but I don't know if it is sending the cord to the Arduino. Here is my code any help would be apprenticed.

Arduino code:

```
#include <Servo.h>

//1439
//899
Servo myservo;
Servo myservo1; 

//String cordXstr;
//String cordYstr;
String cord; 
int cordx = 0;
int cordy = 0;  

 
void setup() {
  myservo.attach(9);
  myservo1.attach(10);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}
 
void loop() {
cord = Serial.read();
if (cord[0] == 'x'){
      cord.remove(0,1);
    cordx = cord.toInt();

 }
 cord = Serial.read();
    if (cord[0] == 'y'){
    cord.remove(0,1);
    cordy = cord.toInt();

 }
  

    cordx = map(cordx, 0, 1439, 0, 180);     
    myservo.write(cordx);                  
    delay(15);       
    cordy = map(cordy , 0, 899, 0, 180);     
    myservo.write(cordy);                  
    delay(15);
  
}
```

python code

```
import serial
import pyautogui
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/tty.usbmodem14101', 9600)
while True:
    x, y = pyautogui.position()
    ser.write("x",x)
    ser.write("y",y)
    print(pyautogui.position())
```

Comment: `Serial.read()` reads a single byte not a string.

Comment: "Cords?"  This question is completely unintelligible.

Comment: TomServo, cords is a short version of saying coordinates.

Comment: just use coords like everyone else on this planet

Comment: ohhhhhhhhh wait people say coords? I always thought it was cords

Answer (score 0):

> I can run both programs

How?

Your Arduino sketch does not compile because you never declare `myservo`

`ser.write("x"x)` causes a syntax error. You mean something like `` "x"+`x` ``  (I'm no Python expert)

You lack the very basics of serial communication. You attempt to write 'x' followed by an integer. Then you try to read a single byte and if equasl 'x', remove the first character of that byte (you only have 1!) and then convert that to an integer.
Then you read a second byte and attempt to do the same mistake without even checking wether you received something.

Please refer to the Arduino manual to see what the functions you're using actually do and how to use them properly.

https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/communication/serial/

Doing a few Arduino / Python serial tutorials will also help.

Comment: k thanks, ya I am very new to serial monitor and Arduino I will go check out those links thanks for ur help

Comment: also I have no clue why I can run both programs it just works